# Как найти в слайсе какие цифры встречаются чаще всего?

Tags: golang

Подскажите: как в слайсе можно найти цифры, которые встречаются чаще всего в Go?

Comment: вам алгоритм нужен?

Comment: да,  сам сделал что то в этом роде https://play.golang.org/p/LUs3LZQ9xlN но это не то

Comment: вам нужна map[int]int, где будете хранить число-количество. вы поняли мою подсказку?

Comment: Вас понял, спасибо большое за подсказку.

Comment: как решите - опубликуйте ваше решение как ответ

Comment: сделал так,  в качестве ключа как вы сказали число, а значение сколько раз встречается https://play.golang.org/p/XYcH5-D2UQC

Answer (score 0):

```go
func main() {
    // допустим, цифры хранятся в массиве x
    var y map[int]int
    for _,el:=range x {
        y[el]=y[el]+1
    }
}
```